# Why does Beautiful Soup view '<' as invalid character?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to use Beautiful Soup to pull css elements for the first time and I am consistently getting the following error regardless of which css element I attempt to select:

> soupsieve.util.SelectorSyntaxError: Invalid character '<' position 0
> line 1:

`soup.select("<span class="regular-price" data-ui="size-color-price">$230.00</span>)`

I feel like I am missing something fundamental regarding the use of the 'less than symbol' so I have tried manually typing in the CSS element as well (assuming there might be some formatting I couldn't see) but the issue continues

Comment: U have to enter the ```css selector``` in ```soup.select``` instead of typing out the entire element. Right click on the element and click copy css selector. Then, paste the css selector in ```soup.select```.

Comment: That's not valid python (the python string is using double quotes as are the xml attributes). Can you fix that so we see excactly what you are using as a selector?

Answer (score 4):

`soup.select` accepts the `css selector` of the element as the argument. So you have to enter the `css selector` in `soup.select` instead of typing out the entire element.

Right click on the element and click `copy css selector`. Then, paste the `css selector` in `soup.select`. Thus, this is how your code should look like:

```
soup.select('css selector of the element')
```

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup has two methods that require CSS selectors, `.select()` and `.select_one()`. First method selects multiple elements based on the selector, the second one selects just one. For example, to select price from your HTML snippet, you would do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''<span class="regular-price" data-ui="size-color-price">$230.00</span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

price = soup.select_one('span.regular-price')
print(price.text)
```

Prints:

```
$230.00
```